# Problems understanding Dexie Encrypted

Tags: encryption, dexie

Could somebody help me with `dexie-encrypted` found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dexie-encrypted) . The documentation provided was pretty short and was missing real-life examples of how to actually encrypt and decrypt the data from `indexDb`.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a project using dexie-encrypted you will get idea how it will works.
Dexie encrypted has outdated documentation which is based on previous version
In the latest version they changed out the functions name

```
import { applyEncryptionMiddleware } from "dexie-encrypted";
import { cryptoOptions } from "dexie-encrypted";
import { clearAllTables } from "dexie-encrypted";
const nacl = require("tweetnacl");

const keyPair = nacl.sign.keyPair.fromSeed(new Uint8Array(32));


applyEncryptionMiddleware(
  db,
  keyPair.publicKey,
  {
    friends: {
      type: cryptoOptions.ENCRYPT_LIST,
      fields: ["ssn", "phone"] // note: these cannot be indices
    },
    enemies: cryptoOptions.NON_INDEXED_FIELDS
  },
  clearAllTables
);

db.version(5).stores({
  friends: "++id",
  enemies: "++id"
});
```

You can also find
check this out
https://codesandbox.io/s/dexie-encrypted-working-example-2hiqu

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30696409)